# Page don't work when I set the error404 handler (app.get('*', ......))

Tags: node.js, express, routes, url-routing

I am trying to set the error404 handler. As I have looked around here, I should set the '*' path to the error404.jade page at the final of the rest of the routings.

When do so, the page doesn't load the images, or css or javascript files. This don't make sense to me.

app.ts

```
import express = require('express');
import routes = require('./routes/index');
import http = require('http');
import path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.login);
app.get('/home', routes.home);
app.get('/markets', routes.markets);
app.get('/market/*', routes.specific_market);
app.get('/trades', routes.trades);
app.get('/about', routes.about);
app.get('/contact', routes.contact);
//app.get('*', routes.error404);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

index.ts

```
/*
 * GET home page.  
 */
import express = require('express');
import market_routes = require('./market-routes');
import trade_routes = require('./trade-routes');
import data = require('../Scripts/data-test');

// STATIC PAGES
export function login(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    res.render('login', { title: 'Login', user, year: new Date().getFullYear() });
};
export function about(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    res.render('about', { title: 'About', user, year: new Date().getFullYear(), message: 'Description page' });
};
export function contact(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    res.render('contact', { title: 'Contact', user, year: new Date().getFullYear(), message: 'Contact page' });
};
export function error404(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    res.render('error404', { title: 'Not Found', user, year: new Date().getFullYear(), message: 'Error page' });
};

var user = data.user;

export function home(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    res.render('home', { title: 'Home', user, year: new Date().getFullYear() });
};

export function markets(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) { market_routes.markets(req, res); };
export function specific_market(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) { market_routes.specific_market(req, res); };

export function trades(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) { trade_routes.trades(req, res); };
export function advanced_trades(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) { trade_routes.advanced_trades(req, res); };
```

[(img) Page with the line 'uncommented'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsxgU.png)

[(img) Page with the line 'commented'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAOAB.png)

Comment: your statics arent found. try using the rote without `'*'`, just `app.use(routes.error404);`

Comment: @JohannesMerz YEES!!! That works! Thanks a lot

Comment: i created an official answer so others can see.

Answer (score 0):

Your statics arent found. use the route without `'*'`:

```
app.use(routes.error404);
```